# How do you calculate the change in entropy for a non quasistatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, equilibrium

I understand that Entropy is a state function, but the change in entropy does in fact depend on the process from a-->b. I understand the derivation for entropy where 
$$S_2-S_1=Ncv\ln\frac{T_2}{T_1}+NR\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$ but this requires that the process is quasistatic. Is there a form of this equation that applies to non-quasistatic processes?

Comment: That equation you mentioned can be used between *any* two equilibrium states of an ideal gas, even if the process between those states was non-quasistatic. An example would be free expansion of the gas.

Answer (score 1):

RECIPE FOR DETERMINING THE CHANGE IN ENTROPY FOR AN IRREVERSIBLE PROCESS

1. Apply the First Law of Thermodynamics to the irreversible process to determine the final thermodynamic equilibrium state of the system
2. Totally forget about the actual irreversible process (it is of no further use), and focus instead exclusively on the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states. This is the most important step.
3. Devise a reversible path between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium states (end points).  This reversible path does not have to bear any resemblance whatsoever to the actual irreversible process path.   For example, even if the actual irreversible process is adiabatic, the reversible path you devise does not have to be adiabatic.  You can even separate various parts of the system from one another, and subject each of them to a different reversible path, as long as they all end up in their correct final states. Plus, there are an infinite number of reversible process paths that can take you from the initial state to the final state, and they will all give exactly the same value for the change in entropy.  So try to devise a path that is simple to work with (i.e., for which it is easy to apply step 4).
4. For the selected reversible path, evaluate the integral of dq/T from the initial state to the final state, where dq is the incremental amount of heat added to the system along the sequence of changes comprising the reversible path.  This will be your change of entropy S.  That is, $\Delta S=\int{\frac{dq_{rev}}{T}}$, where the subscript rev refers to the reversible path.

FOR SEVERAL WORKED EXAMPLES OF APPLYING THIS PROCEDURE TO SPECIFIC IRREVERSIBLE PROCESSES, SEE THE FOLLOWING LINK:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Answer (score 0):

For general non-equilibrium processes there exists no such relation, as the final entropy can fluctuate over repetitions of the process. To put it another way, each time you perform the experiment, you may exchange different amounts of entropy with the heat bath, and so the final entropy may not be the same.

The equivalent concept in non-equilibrium thermodynamics are the various fluctuation theorems, of which the [Crooks fluctuation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crooks_fluctuation_theorem) is one example, and a corollary of this is the [Jarzynski equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarzynski_equality).

Comment: Take free expansion of a gas, for example. That's a non-quasistatic process, each state is not in equilibrium with the prior state. The $\Delta S$ that @Dragonbeast mentioned can still be used in such a case.

Comment: Nevertheless the equation does not apply to *general* non-equilibrium processes.

Comment: If the initial and final states of an ideal gas are thermodynamic equilibrium states and the mass of the gas is constant, the equation written by the OP is independent of the process path, and does indeed apply to general non-equilibrium processes.  Entropy is a function of state, and depends only on the two end points.  I support @Drew 's comment.

Comment: I don't believe anything contrary to that was said! But OP did not say that the final and end states are equilibrium states, so I did not assume it was so.